# How can i remove this space?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can i remove this height space in css?

```
.row{
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row > a{
padding: 0;
border: 4px solid transparent;
position: relative;
}
```

[image: height space]

Comment: Reduce the height of the picture on the right

Comment: Try adding `align-items: flex-end` to `.row`.

Comment: @Andreas i am changed the height to auto but it's not working. https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEXNA.png

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't unless you use a masonary style grid with CSS and maybe some JS. Something like this below.

https://medium.com/@andybarefoot/a-masonry-style-layout-using-css-grid-8c663d355ebb

Comment: Haha why would anyone down vote this!

Comment: Because the example you've quoted here use Javascript to solve the problem. @Yusuf has specified "How can I remove thisspace in css".

Comment: Yes and I answered by saying you can't! I suggested an extended solution that's all. You could actually do it with CSS but you'd run into problems at every turn working on the assumption it would be used in a responsive environment and more images would be added.

Comment: thanks you are right, i should use masonary style.

Comment: we can perfectly use CSS for this, the issue is that the OP didn't share relevant information about his code so we cannot help him

Comment: @TemaniAfif ok then share the solution using pure CSS, that would be awesome!